# Migrating App Kit to Ember CLI - ReferenceError window is not defined

Tags: ember.js

After discovering that Ember App Kit along with useage of Grunt are depricated now, I installed Ember CLI and tried to migrate a fresh copy of the App Kit to Ember CLI by running 'ember init', but I got this error 'ReferenceError: window is not defined at Object.'. I also ran 'npm install' and 'bower install' to get dependent modules, but still 'ember init' won't run. It seems that there's a problem with 'window' in 'config\environment.js'.

Rather than migrating the old App Kit, shouldn't we have a new starter kit based on Ember CLI?

Comment: Ember CLI is the new starter kit. If you are starting a fresh project, Ember App Kit is entirely unnecessary.

Comment: Hmm, yes I found a tutorial where you just type 'ember new projectname' and it scaffolds up a new 'projectname' with Ember 1.10, htmlbars and no grunt. Nice but I have 2 projects built out last summer based on the EAK so if migration worked on a base EAK, then I would then try it on my built out projects. The EAK site at github doesn't say that migration doesn't actually work or what to do about 'window is not defined'. Well, now that I have a new 'beta CLI' project, I'm going to attempt to add my Routes and MVC code and see what it takes to do manual migration/upgrade.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While the old EAK project site suggests that you can migrate it to CLI, I found that to be problematic. But there's no need to start with the EAK anymore since Ember CLI will scaffold up a new starter project for you.